# Fuzzy matching/approximate string matching: many-to-many case in R

Tags: r, string-matching, fuzzy

I have two datasets. The first dataset has names of politicians, a variable for year and their wealth in that year. As a result, one name might be repeated several times. I have another dataset with the same variable. Some names overlap while others don't. The years are different to the first dataset. There are spelling errors, title omissions etc in observations in both the datasets. I want to perform fuzzy matching. I have no idea how it works. Any help/resources will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Riddhimma. Stack overflow is a great site if you have a specific programming question, but this means showing an example of the data that you have, with the expected output. A description of the problem using only words isn't really adequate to get the help you are looking for, particularly when it comes to parsing text or string matching, since this is dependent on the exact format of your data. Please include sample input and expected output. I'm afraid recommendations for off-site resources is off-topic here. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the `fuzzyjoin` package.

Comment: Fuzzy matching is common and R has some tools and packages to help. See https://www.statology.org/fuzzy-matching-in-r/ for an intro.